# Setting of timezone works properly on localhost but fails on remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my remote server i want to change the timezone to suit my needs. i've done the correct in .htacess which works fine on the local but when i uploaded to the remote server i got an error: ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

```
#Adjust default time zone
php_value date.timezone Africa/Accra
```

Comment: Please use this..
#Adjust default time zone
php_value date.timezone = "Africa/Accra";

Answer (score 0):

If you can, it'd be best to define it in your PHP script:

```
date_default_timezone_set ("Africa/Accra");
```

If you need it in your .htaccess file, try quoting it:

```
php_value date.timezone "Africa/Accra"
```

Comment: You may be running an old version of PHP. Try: "SetEnv TZ Africa/Accra" (without the quotes). If that doesn't work, you can also try: <IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value date.timezone "Africa/Accra"
</IfModule> . If they still don't work, then I have no idea how to fix it.